# How can I sort a multidimensional array by the highest value of each row?

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I'm working on system to keep track on players, their three scores, and then figure out winner. The winner is the one with highest score amongst three individual takes. So in other words, the scores don't add up, it's just their highest which matters.

As an example, I've just got values here hardcoded in. The array's first index-number is in the order of the names. So John got 42, 38 then 43 points and so on.

```
    string[] player = {"John", "Jack", "Joe", "Jim", "Jacob"};
    int[,] stats = {
               {42, 38, 43},
               {37, 36, 39},
               {35, 40, 37},
               {41, 44, 38},
               {33, 34, 37}
               };
```

Now I want to make a function which identifies which player had the highest score amongst these three attempts and show the three top scores (one per person) in order with name.
So output in a label would finally be something like this::

- 1.)  Jim - 44
- 2.)  John - 42
- 3.)  Joe - 40

So, as I see it, problem arises that each row has to be examined for its highest value, and then a new array could be made while still keeping track on who owns the score, to properly print it. (I'm new to this.) Does anyone have an idea of how this result could be achieved?

Comment: Seems like you understand the steps needed to solve the problem.  Where are you stuck?

Comment: Multidimensional arrays are rarely a good choice for storing data.  There's not a lot of API support for performing queries, aggregations, or transforms on them.  Are you required to use multidimensional arrays for this?

Comment: If we can do this with List<T> and a "Player" object this becomes really easy. Is that an acceptable solution?

Comment: I suggest using `for` loops to get your feet wet programming in C#.  Then you can move on to more elegant solutions, such as LINQ.  Take a stab at it, and show us your code when you get stuck.

Answer (score 2):

Linq has a cool feature called "Zip" which basically acts like a zipper on two enumerable collections.  It goes item by item and creates a result based on the items at the same index in each collection.

So you could do something like this:

```
 player.Zip(stats,(p,i) => new { Player = p, HighScore = i.Max() })
       .OrderBy(m => m.HighScore)
```

You can then do a foreach over that result to print our your winners in order.

Edit: Not 100% sure that will work with the multi-dimensional array. Hopefully it gets you in the right direction.

Comment: Problem is that a rectangular array is effectively a single collection--it's not a sequence of sequences like a jagged array would be.  I don't think you can apply a `Zip` operator to separate one dimension out from the others.

Comment: Neat solution without the need for an extra class though. Cool idea!

Comment: @Mike, yea I think you're right.  Oh well..would have been a nice streamlined way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Player
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public List<int> Score { get; set; }
        }

List<Player> playerList = new List<Player>();
            playerList.Add(new Player() { Name = "John", Score = new List<int>() { 42, 38, 43 } });
            playerList.Add(new Player() { Name = "Jack", Score = new List<int>() { 37, 36, 39 } });
            playerList.Add(new Player() { Name = "Joe", Score = new List<int>() { 35, 40, 37 } });
            playerList.Add(new Player() { Name = "Jim", Score = new List<int>() { 41, 44, 38 } });
            playerList.Add(new Player() { Name = "Jacob", Score = new List<int>() { 33, 34, 37 } });

        var result2 = from p in playerList orderby p.Score.Max() descending select p;
var result = from p in playerList where p.Score.Max() == ((from x in playerList select new { x.Name, MaxScore = x.Score.Max() }).Max(x => x.MaxScore)) select p;
```